# How do I get rid of white background on my SWF file?

Tags: flash, background, whitespace, preloader

I'm putting a SWF file into an HTML page in GoLive, and even though all my code and SWF file are set to a blue background, there is a quick second during the loading of each page where my entire SWF document is completely white on top of the blue HTML background. I don't know if this is making sense, but check out www.eloquentcreative.com to see the issue in action. If you refresh the page or click thorough the navigation, you'll see a quick second of the entire SWF file area turning entirely white before the preloader of the next page starts. It might seem like a small thing, but it's driving me crazy and I feel it kills the professionalism of the site a considerable amount.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add wmode = transparent to your HTML object.  If you're using SWFObject, this is done with:

```
so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
```

Otherwise, add this to your obeject params:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

And this to your embed tag:

```
wmode="transparent"
```

You can also just set the background color, which may be a more suitable solution for your particular problem.  With SWFObject, the background color is one of the parameters when you instantiate the SWFObject class.  Otherwise, add the following to your object tag:

```
<param name="bgcolor" value="#XXXXXX" />
```

and the following to your embed tag:

```
bgcolor="#XXXXXX"
```

Where #XXXXXX is the color you'd like to use.

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this - I've had issues with using transparent mode if you have Javascript-based popups over it, eg the "Share this" button that a lot of sites have now.  Transparent mode makes the popup appear behind the flash non-transparent content, so it can look a bit odd, but YMMV.

Comment: Is that right?  I think transparent mode is actually what allows javascript popups to appear on top of flash content.  Flash content always appears on top without it.